# Add icon to a link cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'd like to add a icon `<i>` tag to a Cakephp link. 
Here is my code :

```
<?= $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-shopping-cart')).'Cart', array('controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart')) ?>
```

This line generates :

```
<a href="/cakephp-shopping-cart/shop/cart">&lt;i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;Cart</a>
```

Why `<` is replaced by its hexa value? My charset is UTF-8.

Thanks!

Comment: I've got a handy little plugin for creating links containing font awesome links (https://github.com/drmonkeyninja/cakephp-font-awesome). It makes sure that any text in a link containing a Font Awesome icon is properly escaped, but also handles the case of just an icon. For example, for your case you could do the following: `echo $this->Fa->link('shopping-cart', 'Cart', array('controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart'));`

Comment: Nice! I'm going to try it, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add option `'escape'` set to `false`:

```
<?= $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'fa fa-shopping-cart')).'Cart', array('controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart'), array('escape' => false)) ?>
```

Documentation page about [`HtmlHelper`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link).

Answer (score 0):

Html->link($this->Html->tag('i', '',['class' => 'fa fa-shopping-cart']).'Cart',['controller' => 'shop', 'action' => 'cart'], ['escape' => false]); ?>

Comment: This is basically same answer as provided by @marian0

Comment: You might need to use this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make your post appear as intended and not be perceived as broke code. But if you do so, please also add an explanation of how your code works, why it solves the problem and especially what the benefit over the seemingly only sublty different existing, upvoted and accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33919228/7733418 is.